# У span не работает margin-top

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Вот HTML:

```
<div class="header">
   <span id="header1"><img src="images/Shesterenka.gif"></img><a href="#">Служба поддержки</a></span>
   <span id="header1"><img src="images/chelovek.gif"></img><a href="#">Вакансии</a></span>
   <span id="header1"><a href="#">Войти</a></span>
   <span id="header1"><a href="#">Зарегестрироваться</a></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header{
   background-color:#285023;
   height: 44px;
}

.header a {
   text-decoration: none;
}

#header1 {
   color: #ffffff;
   font-family:Roboto;
   font-size: 15px;
   margin-top: 18px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Нельзя указывать всем элементам один и тот же id.
2) У span`a не может быть margin-top, т.к. это не блочный элемент

Вот исправленный *HTML*:

```
<div class="header">
   <span class="header1"><img src="images/Shesterenka.gif"></img><a href="#">Служба поддержки</a></span>
   <span class="header1"><img src="images/chelovek.gif"></img><a href="#">Вакансии</a></span>
   <span class="header1"><a href="#">Войти</a></span>
   <span class="header1"><a href="#">Зарегестрироваться</a></span>
</div>
```

Вот нужный *CSS*:

```
.header{
   background-color:#285023;
   height: 44px;
}

.header a {
   text-decoration: none;
}

.header1 {
   display: inline-block; /* Я добавил это */
   color: #ffffff;
   font-family:Roboto;
   font-size: 15px;
   margin-top: 18px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```