# Не выполняется margin-top для элемента

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. При определении элементу `<span class="e-mail">` значения `margin-top` никак не меняется его положение. Пожалуйста, подскажите в чём проблема?

```css
.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#text-title {
  font-size: 4.5vh;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-div {
  width: 93.7%;
  height: 70%;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgba(333, 333, 333, .5);
  margin-top: 8.5vh;
  margin-left: 5vh;
  border: 3.5px solid black;
}
.text-part {
  width: 40%;
  padding-top: 6vh;
}
.one {
  font-size: 2.40vh;
  font-family: impact, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  margin-left: 4vh; 
}
.two p{
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: Courier New, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 5vh;
}
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#number {
  margin-left: 67.5px; 
}
.e-mail {
  font-size: 2.40vh;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: impact, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  margin-left: 4vh;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#e-adress {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.91vh;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: Courier New, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 5vh;
}
#adress_title {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: impact, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  margin-left: 4vh;
}
#adress_text p {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 14.5px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: Courier New, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 4vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
<section>
<div class="container2">
    <p id="text-title"> Наши контакты:</p>
    <div class="main-div">
        <div class="text-part">
            <span class="one">
                Напишите или позвоните нам:<br>
            </span>
            <span class="two">
                <p>
                    <span class="underline">Иерей Роман Клевцов</span>: 89514083313 <br>
                    <span class="underline">Матушка Нина</span>: <span id="number">89514083312</span>
                </p>
            </span>
            <span class="e-mail">
                E-mail:
                <div id="e-adress">
                    klevcovra@mail.ru
                </div>
            </span>
            <p><span id="adress_title">
                Наш адрес:
            </span></p>
            <span id="adress_text">
                <p>Россия,Омская область,Калачинский<br> район,с.Воскресенка,Пионерская,6</p>
            </span>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Во-первых, для inline-элементов вертикальные маргины не работают. Во-вторых, вы вкладываете block-элементы внутрь inline-элементов, что запрещено. В-третьих, у вас один незакрытый div

Comment: В-четвёртых, дубликат вопроса: [У span не работает margin-top](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610174/%d0%a3-span-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-margin-top)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элемент `span` по умолчанию имеет `display: inline` позиционирование. При таком позиционировании вертикальные `margin`-ы не работают.

При `inline` позиционировании элементы ведут себя как слова в строчке, и позиционируются по очереди, когда место заканчивается идёт переход на следующую строку. То есть реальная форма занимаемая при таком позиционировании элементом это набор прямоугольников (как кусок текста из произвольного места).

При `display: block` и `inline-block` элемент ведёт себя как прямоугольник, в этом случае все `margin` учитываются.

Почитать про `display` позиционирование можно [тут](https://metanit.com/web/html5/8.5.php).